# Angular 10 Upload Image in ngFOR

Tags: angular, image, upload

How i can change img crs when uploading image in ngFOR

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products"  >
  <input type='file' #fileInput (change)='onFileUpdate($event,product) style="display:none;'/>
  <img  [src]='product.imgUrl' (click) = 'fileInput.click()' />      
</div>
```

Comment: are you uploading image on BE or directly showing on UI ?

Comment: when i choose image in upload input i want to change src  image

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public products = [
    {
      id: 1,
      imgUrl: "",
      imgBase64Data: ""
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      imgUrl: "",
      imgBase64Data: ""
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      imgUrl: "",
      imgBase64Data: ""
    }
  ];

  onFileUpdate(event, index) {
    const files = event.target.files;
    if (files.length === 0) return;

    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    reader.onload = _event => {
      this.products[index].imgBase64Data = reader.result as string;
    };
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index">
  <input type='file' #fileInput (change)="onFileUpdate($event, i)" />
  <img *ngIf="product.imgBase64Data" [src]='product.imgBase64Data' (click) = 'fileInput.click()' width="100" height="100"/>
</div>
```

You can upload image and convert into base 64 data. Then you can show it on UI.
If you have to save images on BE, then you can send base 64 data to BE also.

You can check [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-image-upload) here.

Let me know if you have any doubt.